# Closed Form Ridge Regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression, linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding the output of my function to implement multiple-ridge regression. I am doing this from scratch in Python for the closed form of the method. This closed form is shown below:

[image: Closed form]

I have a training set `X` that is `100 rows x 10 columns` and a vector `y` that is `100x1`.

My attempt is as follows:

```
def ridgeRegression(xMatrix, yVector, lambdaRange):
    wList = []

    for i in range(1, lambdaRange+1):
        lambVal = i

        # compute the inner values (X.T X + lambda I)
        xTranspose = np.transpose(x)
        xTx = xTranspose @ x
        lamb_I = lambVal * np.eye(xTx.shape[0])

        # invert inner, e.g. (inner)**(-1)
        inner_matInv = np.linalg.inv(xTx + lamb_I)

        # compute outer (X.T y)
        outer_xTy = np.dot(xTranspose, y)

        # multiply together
        w = inner_matInv @ outer_xTy
        wList.append(w)

    print(wList)
```

For testing, I am running it with the first 5 lambda values.
`wList` becomes 5 `numpy.arrays` each of length 10 (I'm assuming for the 10 coefficients).

Here is the first of those 5 arrays:

```
array([ 0.29686755,  1.48420319,  0.36388528,  0.70324668, -0.51604451,
        2.39045735,  1.45295857,  2.21437745,  0.98222546,  0.86124358])
```

My question, and clarification:

Shouldn't there be 11 coefficients, (1 for the y-intercept + 10 slopes)?
How do I get the `Minimum Square Error` from this computation?
What comes next if I wanted to plot this line?

I think I am just really confused as to what I'm looking at, since I'm still working on my linear-algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: @Prune will do, thanks!

Comment: Never use inverses. Numpy has a solve method for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would modify your ridge regression to look like the following:

```
import numpy as np
def ridgeRegression(X, y, lambdaRange):
    wList = []
    # Get normal form of `X`
    A = X.T @ X 
    # Get Identity matrix
    I = np.eye(A.shape[0])
    # Get right hand side
    c = X.T @ y
    for lambVal in range(1, lambdaRange+1):
        # Set up equations Bw = c        
        lamb_I = lambVal * I
        B = A + lamb_I
        # Solve for w
        w = np.linalg.solve(B,c)
        wList.append(w)        
    return wList
```

Notice that I replaced your `inv` call to compute the matrix inverse with an implicit solve. This is much more numerically stable, which is an important consideration for these types of problems especially.

I've also taken the `A=X.T@X` computation, identity matrix `I` generation, and right hand side vector `c=X.T@y` computation out of the loop--these don't change within the loop and are relatively expensive to compute.

As was pointed out by @qwr, the number of columns of `X` will determine the number of coefficients you have. You have not described your model, so it's not clear how the underlying domain, `x`, is structured into `X`.

Traditionally, one might use polynomial regression, in which case `X` is the [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). In that case, the first coefficient would be associated with the y-intercept. However, based on the context of your question, you seem to be interested in multivariate linear regression. In any case, the model needs to be clearly defined. Once it is, then the returned weights may be used to further analyze your data.

Comment: the given formula suggests ordinary linear regression with a regularization term

Comment: Thank you @HAL9001. This has helped put me in the right direction of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Typically to make notation more compact, the matrix `X` contains a column of ones for an intercept, so if you have `p` predictors, the matrix is dimensions `n` by `p+1`. See [Wikipedia article on linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) for an example.
2. To compute in-sample MSE, use the definition for MSE: the *average of squared residuals*. To compute generalization error, you need cross-validation.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you shouldn't take `lambVal` as an integer. It can be small (close to 0) if the aim is just to avoid numerical error when `xTx` is ill-conditionned.

I would advise you to use a logarithmic range instead of a linear one, starting from 0.001 and going up to 100 or more if you want to. For instance you can change your code to that:

```
powerMin = -3
powerMax = 3

for i in range(powerMin, powerMax):
    lambVal = 10**i
    print(lambVal)
```

And then you can try a smaller range or a linear range once you figure out what is the correct order of `lambVal` with your data from cross-validation.